# Is it possible to simplify Scala method arguments declaration using macros?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-2.10

Methods are often declared with obvious parameter names, e.g.

```
def myMethod(s: String, image: BufferedImage, mesh: Mesh) { ... }
```

Parameter names correspond to parameter types.

1) "s" is often used for String

2) "i" for Int

3) lowercased class name for one word named classes (Mesh -> mesh)

4) lowercased last word from class name for long class names (BufferedImage -> image)

(Of course, it would not be convenient for ALL methods and arguments. Of course, somebody would prefer other rules…)

Scala macros are intended to generate some expressions in code. I would like to write some specific macros to convert to correct Scala expressions something like this:

```
// "arguments interpolation" style
// like string interpolation
def myMethod s[String, BufferedImage, Mesh] 
{ /* code using vars "s", "image", "mesh" */ }

// or even better:
mydef myMethod[String, BufferedImage, Mesh] 
{ /* code using vars "s", "image", "mesh" */ }
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do this? This will only create your very own scala dialect, with all the confusion that comes with it, without any palatable benefit.

Comment: Seems like every macros creates new dialect of Scala… I just want to write less code, without any duplication. Parameter names look like crowd of micro code duplications. And, if it is possible to create such macros, we can experiment with it, improve it and even try to make it common and popular.

Comment: Yes this is true, in some way every macro creates some dialect, but they do it to enable something that is not readily doable in plain scala (at least not without a lot of boiler-plate or not efficiently). Or in other word, they bring something new and valuable, which is supposed to largely make up for the downsides of departing from plain scala. Not only your proposition does not bring much, but it is very vague ("s" for String? Where will you end? will you need a giant cheat sheet to knwo the types/names of all your parameters?). Just my 2 cents.

Comment: I don't want my own Scala completely without argument names. I just want some macros to avoid duplication where argument name is totally obvious. Given "rules" are just an example. Nowadays I just can not experiment with it to make it better. But everyone can inspect his own code and see many small and simple methods with this type of duplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it is not possible and probably it will never be. Macros can not introduce their own syntax - they must be represented through valid Scala code (which can be executed at compile time) and, too, they must generate valid Scala code (better say a valid Scala AST).

Both of your shown examples are not valid Scala code, thus Macros can not handle them. Nevertheless, the current nightly build of [Macro Paradise](http://scalamacros.org/news/2012/12/18/macro-paradise.html) includes untyped macros. They allow to write Scala code which is typechecked after they are expanded, this means it is possible to write:

```
forM({i = 0; i < 10; i += 1}) {
  println(i)
}
```

Notice, that the curly braces inside of the first parameter list are needed because, although the code is not typechecked when one writes it, it must represent a valid Scala AST.

The implementation of this macro looks like this:

```
def forM(header: _)(body: _) = macro __forM

def __forM(c: Context)(header: c.Tree)(body: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  header match {
    case Block(
      List(
        Assign(Ident(TermName(name)), Literal(Constant(start))),
        Apply(Select(Ident(TermName(name2)), TermName(comparison)), List(Literal(Constant(end))))
      ),
      Apply(Select(Ident(TermName(name3)), TermName(incrementation)), List(Literal(Constant(inc))))
    ) =>

    // here one can generate the behavior of the loop
    // but omit full implementation for clarity now ...

  }
}
```

Instead of an already typechecked expression, the macro expects only a tree, that is typechecked after the expansion. The method call itself expects two parameter lists, whose parameter types can be delayed after the expansion phase if one uses an underscore.

Currently there is a little bit of [documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html) available but because it is extremely beta a lot of things will probably change in future.

With type macros it is possible to write something like this:

```
object O extends M {
  // traverse the body of O to find what you want
}

type M(x: _) = macro __M

def __M(c: Context)(x: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
  // omit full implementation for clarity ...
}
```

This is nice in order to delay the typechecking of the whole body because it allows to to cool things...

---

Macros that can change Scalas syntax are not planned at the moment and are probably not a good idea. I can't say if they will happen one day only future can tell us this.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the "why" (no really, why do you want to do that?), the answer is no, because as far as I know macros cannot (in their current state) generate methods or types, only expressions.

Comment: Not to mention changing how parsing workings `def x s[...]` wouldn't parse.

Comment: pedrofurla, I don't know an exact possible way, I just want to avoid a duplication. It could look like `def myMethod(string: _, image: _, mesh: _)`. Are you sure there is no any way to do it?

Comment: No there's not. The closest you could probably get here is with type macros (http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/typemacros.html), which can take the body of a class or an object and rewrite it to something else, but type macros will most likely not be released in 2.10.x and might even not be included in 2.11.